# Trying to select child elements that don't have a dynamically added class

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have a form that's in several sections. As the user fills out the form, I want to mark each section completed as they finish it.

To be completed, all required fields must pass a client-side validation.

Fields that don't require validation have the class "ignore".

Fields that have passed validation have the class "success" added by the validation code.

So I want to check a given form section for any form elements that don't have either "ignore" or "success" as a class. If there are any such elements, the section is not complete.

Here's my code:

```
$('.form-section input, .form-section select, .form-section textarea').blur(function() {

    //get containing form section
    formSection = $(this).closest('.form-section');
    //Check for any inputs, selects and textareas that don't have "ignore" or "success"  as a class
    sectionCheck = $(formSection).find('input,select,textarea').not('.ignore','.success').length;
    if(sectionCheck > 0) {alert('not done yet');}
    else{alert('section complete');}    
});
```

It works on static HTML. But in live code it doesn't see the "success" class because that class is added dynamically.

I think I need to somehow use the  on() method, but am not sure how, since the problem isn't the blur() event.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you wrapping `formSection` in a jQuery wrapper? It is already a jQuery collection.

Comment: jsFiddle this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using an older version of the code in the live site, and it had a typo in the jQuery. I misformatted the "not()" statement.

sectionCheck = $(formSection).find('input,select,textarea').not('.ignore','.success').length;

Should have been:

sectionCheck = $(formSection).find('input,select,textarea').not('.ignore,.success').length;

Now it works fine.

Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 1):

When does the validation happen on the fields? Because if the validation is happening after the blur event, you would not be able to detect the addition of "success" class

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class of `dynamic`, and then filter that out when you get the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/BkFsR/)

You will have to assume each field is bad and have something to validate each relevant field as it is "blurred". But when a relevant element is touched / retouched you should mark it dirty for it to be re-validated

```
.on('focus', 'input,select,textarea', function () {
    //mark dirty on focus
    ...
}) 
.on('blur', 'input,select,textarea', function () {
    // validate on blur
    ...
});
```